# How to use WebView in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I need to authenticate user in my app, and for that I want to spawn another window with Cocoa WebView control. The problem is that I can't do anything with that control from C# code, and can't find any documentation for it :(

Trying to use

> WebViewWindow.MainFrame.LoadRequest (Request);

But it throws exception of some kind. How to properly open URL in that WebView? Maybe using something like GeckoFX instead is a good idea?

Also I'll need to get back url that user was redirected to. How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: my answer did solve your problem ? @user3794486

Comment: The exception in question would obviously be useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this

```
public override void AwakeFromNib()
{
    base.AwakeFromNib();
    webView.MainFrame.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest
        (new NSUrl( "http://www.google.com)));

}
```